# A good Azure Blob Storage javascript API?

Tags: javascript, azure, windows-8, winjs, azure-blob-storage

Currently building a Windows 8 app in HTML5/JS. I need a nice little wrapper around windows azure API for uploading binary data.

Can do myself but requires signing etc of each request so just checking to see if there is a good self contained JS library I could use.

Also no jQuery dependencies please!

Cheers.

Comment: Found a couple in the first search results on google for `windows azure javascript api`. Like: http://davidpallmann.blogspot.com/2012/07/introducing-azurequery-javascript.html, and https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node

Comment: Will the users of this application be using their own storage account or your storage account. The reason I'm asking this is because if they're using your storage account, you may want to look at other alternative like SAS URI instead of consuming REST API as is using account name/key in your application.

Comment: Please refer to [our blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/05/windows-azure-storage-client-library-for-windows-runtime.aspx) for more information on the Community Technology Preview (CTP) release of Windows Azure Storage Client Library for Windows Runtime.